# Replace tab and number with special character

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In my huge file,

```
HISEQ1:122:D0P60ACXX:3:1101:8389:1991   77
HISEQ1:122:D0P60ACXX:5:1102:11591:168589    141
```

how can I replace \tab 77 and \tab 141 with /1 and /2, respectively? I prefer bash script, as I have dozens of such files.
Please, explain the answers in case, because regex results to be too confusing...

```
HISEQ1:122:D0P60ACXX:3:1101:8389:1991/1
HISEQ1:122:D0P60ACXX:5:1102:11591:168589/2
```

Comment: You can match them with `\t77` and `\t141` and replace them with `sed`.

Comment: somethins like this? sed -i -e 's/\t77//1/g' txt

Comment: You'd need to escape the `/` for `/1` - and personally, I'd recommend `perl` instead. Also, the text you put in your answer uses spaces instead of tabs; `\s` covers both space and tab.

Comment: What do these refer to `\tab 77 and \tab 141 with \1 and \2` ? Also, there is no tab in the sample text.

Comment: @user3224522 : Your question is inconsistent. You write first that you want to replace by `\1`, but in the example you gave the replacement string is `/1`.

Comment: @user1934428 just a typing error.

Comment: Then please edit your question to fix it. The difference is important, since `\` is sometimes more cumbersome to handle than `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use `perl` instead of `sed`:

```sh
perl -i -pe 's/\s+77/\/1/g' file.txt
perl -i -pe 's/\s+141/\/2/g' file.txt
```

These two commands will look through `file.txt` and perform an in-place replacement in both - first, looking for spaces followed by "77" and replacing with "/1", and then second looking for spaces followed by "141" and replacing with "/2".

If you want to do it in one line, you can use the following:

`perl -1 -pe '$one="\/1"; $two="\/2"; s/(\s+77)|\s+141/$1 ? $one : $two/eg' file.txt`

Since you want to print "/1" and "/2", both of which use escape characters, you need to store the string literals in variables before evaluating them - otherwise you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: is it possible to put everything as one line? :)

Comment: @user3224522 - No, it's not. Each replacement is dependent on which matched. It could be evaled `s///eg` if really necessary.

Comment: @user3224522 Yes it is! You need to use `/eg` to evaluate it as a function, but you can use a conditional statement to change the replacement based on the match.

Comment: thanks @NickReed for patience, explanations and better solutions.

Comment: @NickReed: Note that the OP said he has a large number of files (_dozens_). Instead of spawning a Perl process for each file, it would maybe better to translate all files in a single Perl program.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
sed -E -i 's/ +77/\/1/;s/ +141/\/2/'  Input_file
```

Comment: @user3224522, To save changes into file use `-i` option,see my edit now and lemme know then?

Comment: @user3224522, Can you please check if your file has control M characters? Do once `cat -v file` and lemme know if you see control M characters in your file?